# Is it possible to do version control on my computer system files themselves?

Tags: macos, git, unix, version-control

Here's my problem. I have OSX Lion and I do Web development, BUT I have no real comprehension of what I'm doing when I'm using brew, pear, and the terminal in general. I am working on leveling up, but I still have to work in the meantime. That's why I very often mess up my system files (just tried to install PHPUnit, didn't work, so I deleted other pear directories, still didn't work, and now I end up with a mess).

*It would feel better and relieve a lot of stress to know I can revert* back my changes when I mess up. **So my question is, can I set up a version control like git on all my computer files themselves, so that before any big change, I can save the state of my computer? Or is there any other way to get that same result?**

I think creating different users for my mac is not enough, cause I want to build up my system, and add things to it, so it doesn't really help. **And I'm not sure, but Time Machine is made just to get some files, not to revert my system to some previous state, or can it do it?**

Help would be greatly greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [time machine](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1427)

Comment: You've hit on one of the best features of brew.  It installs everything in /opt/local/Cellar and puts links to all of it in /opt/local/bin which means removing it should be fairly trivial.

Comment: Yes I like the fact that you can create kinds of environments with brew, but the problem is that is doesn't have all the packages I need and I end up using pear and other horrible (for me) stuff like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to me you need to use a VM.
Take snapshots and work without worries. If you mess up you just revert to your last known good snapshot

Comment: It's funny you said that, cause I installed Debian on a VirtualBox to get some basic skills and confidence. The thing is I really want to build up my working environment, and the virtual machine won't bring about the same errors and warning and all, even though it is a tremendous mean of practice. Do you have any idea where I could go from there? Thanks a lot for your answer by the way.

Comment: @user1011444:Sorry, I did not understand what you are asking me :(

Comment: The thing is that it doesn't really solve the problem unless I do everything and work on the virtual machine, no?

Comment: @user1011444:Yes you are right.But what is the problem?You say that you do web development.Just do your development in the VM and deploy it in a physical machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this - you can version control anything... but I wouldn't recommend it (at least not with GIT/SVN/etc - perhaps there's some software designed for this purpose that I'm unaware of).

You'll be tracking version changes for tons of files, temporary, setting files, binaries, etc. Files would be changing all the time and you'd need to stay on top of commits and so forth. Instead I'd recommended just copying folders (backup), making changes, verifying your changes work, then deleting the backups.

It's very easy to overuse version control.

Answer (score 1):

Having an external drive with time machine and allowing it to sync often will allow you to revert certain parts (or all) of the file  system to a certain date.

Comment: Really! You are a genius! How could you think on that? Just kidding.

Comment: I don't really see the point in jumping at the dude's throat.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're under OS X, I'd suggest Time Machine - it is more adapted to what you want to do than a source control versioning. TM is pretty decent at backuping, but there are other solutions if this one doesn't fit your needs.

**EDIT**: as commented by @dstarh, `brew` isolates everything it installs and uses symbolic links when needed. So use it whenever you can, it leaves your system cleans. There's instructions on how to uninstall a software, and in the worst of the cases, you could look at the source of your software's formula and find out what to delete.

Long story short : yes you could, but there's way easier and painless ways to do this.